# Is it possible to reduce the expiry date of public key in gpg?

Tags: gnupg

If I created a GPG public key with an expiration after 10 years and later I wanted to reduce it to 5 years, is it possible?

Also, if I already published the key to a key server, how to make changes there?

Comment: The process for updating the key server will be up to the key server.

Comment: I did a Google search using your title and got several hits back: https://www.g-loaded.eu/2010/11/01/change-expiration-date-gpg-key/